# Deeplink not handle http and https scheme

Tags: android, flutter

I have used the following code to handle deep links in Android

```
<!-- Deep linking -->
<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mywebsite.com" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

But when I set the scheme to HTTP or HTTPS, it doesn't work and the website opens in the browser.

This code opens the website in the browser:

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="mywebsite.com" />
```

This code will open my app:

```
<data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="app" />
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? You have to solve the http or https issues, the domain name issue in your hosting.

Comment: @Alakba I want my app to open when my website link is clicked instead of the website opening in the browser. I put mywebsite.com as an example in the question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot request domain login for android app. If you want a web project, then you should write codes related to the web project. Even then, you'll be using "localhost".

Answer (score 0):

In `android:host="app.page.link"` would be same as you set in your firebase dynamic link

It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vSMm.png)